# Wordpress setup on existing node server

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, express, web-deployment-project

I have a website running on node/express as [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). It is running on ubuntu server. I am new to WordPress and trying to set up WordPress so that I can create blogs on [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog).

I have created a new directory as blog under public folder and installed WordPress in it.
I have also setup MySQL and everything, but [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog) is showing an error **Cannot GET /blog/**.

Can anyone please here, tell me how to fix it. Or, how can I setup WordPress for blogs on existing non-WordPress website?

Comment: wordpress needs a LAMP stack (you're missing Apache / NGINX  and PHP)

Comment: @GrafiCode Apache is not needed. Just a Webserver that can handle PHP. I prefer NGINX. psel you need to install a webserver and php. Use then the webserver as reverse proxy for you node app and as "regular" webserver for your blog under "/blog" I dont know what you use case for node is, but if you just serve static files with it, then its obsolete and the webserver does the job.

Comment: @Marc LAMP, LEMP, whatever

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set up php server and a compatible SQL db. And point [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog) to that server. Depending on how you've set up the server, pointing to /blog would turn out to be different.

You could for instance use npm module http-proxy to do proxy redirect from the node express server to wordpress once that's up and running.

Comment: thanks @kevin, php server was missing.